# ttyUSB0 permission changes after restart

Tags: permissions, usb, devices

I'm trying to install a device. I plug in the device which creates a `ttyUSB0` file. When I open it in the program I need it for, it says the permission is denied. I type in terminal

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This resolved the problem but after restarting my computer I get the same problem and need to re-enter the same command to get permission. How do I fix this where I don't need to change the permission after every reboot?

Answer (score 9):

You can write udev rule to solve this. Google Keywords: **udev usb permissions**

You can take reference of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/15643) and [this](http://www.frankmeffert.de/udev-usb-and-permissions/) links.

Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-my_usb_device` (for instance). And put the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"
```

Where **HEX1** and **HEX2** are replaced with the vendor and product id respectively. You can get vendor and product id from `lsusb -vvv` command.

Comment: thanks a lot ill try this when i get home and post the results :)

Answer (score 3):

in case you need to change (like me) ttyACM0 permissions,
this are my settings:

`KERNEL=="ttyACM0", MODE="0777"`

It failed when I tried to specify the vendor and product id. I am not sure why.

If you want to restart udev without restarting the machine do this: (Redhat, EL6, Fedora)

`udevadm control --reload-rules` 


`start_udev`